# A product of maximal ideals is zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Show that the zero ideal is a product of maximal ideals (not necessarily distinct) in the ring $k[x,y,z]/(x(x-1),y^2,z^3)$.

I tried using Nullstellensatz and then the 4th Isomorphism Theorem, to get that the maximal ideals in this ring are of the form $(x-a_1,y-a_2,z-a_3)$ where $a_i\in k$. Then essentially I should get a product of these ideals to be equal $(x(x-1)\cdot p_1,y^2\cdot p_2,z^3\cdot p_3)$ where $p_i\in k[x,y,z]$, but I always end up with unwanted elements, e.g., $$(x(x-1),xy,xz,y(x-1),y^2,yz,z(x-1),yz,z^2)\not=(0).$$

Comment: Maybe you just need to add more ideals. I think you need two different ideals, and a product of eight ideals.

Comment: Did you forget to mention that $k$ is algebraically closed?

Comment: @user26857 I don't think that is necessary here, since those ideals will always be maximal (assuming $k$ is a field), they just might not be all of them.

Comment: Anyway, the maximal ideals of your ring are $m_1=(x,y,z)$ and $m_2=(x-1,y,z)$ no matter if $k$ is algebraically closed or not. Now let's see what is $m_1m_2$ and what you need in order to get $0$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Did I say that is necessary? I just looked at his argument.

Comment: @user26857 Ahh, true, the appeal to Nullstellensatz does use it.

Comment: @user26857 I actually calculated $m_1m_2$ in my example. If I remove the terms equal to zero I end up with $m_1m_2=(xy,xz,y(x-1),yz,z(x-1),z^2)$. Multiplying by $m_1$ or $m_2$ again seems incredibly tedious though.

Comment: Multiplying again is not actually that bad, since more and more things will disappear. But as I said, I think you need a product with eight factors.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft You were right. Ended up with $(m_1m_2)^4=(0)$. Appreciate it.